# Discrete value to continuous scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

Good morning, colleagues! Now I try to build the graph - Japanese candles through the ggplot package in R, but the code doesn't want to work. The error is:

> Discrete value supplied to continuous scale.

I suggest that the data are not shown as numeric for ggplot but if I change in the code: `as.vector` --> `as.numeric`, the problem does not disappear. Could you say me what I do wrong. Thanks.

```
library("dplyr")
library("ggplot2")
library("quantmod")
getSymbols('AAPL')
x<-AAPL
head(x)

start=as.Date("2017-01-01")
end=as.Date("2017-09-01")
candle <- function(x, start, end){
date <- as.Date(time(x))
  open <- as.vector(Op(x))
  high <- as.vector(Hi(x))
  low <- as.vector(Lo(x))
  close <- as.vector(Cl(x))
xSubset <-data.frame('date'=date,'open'=open,'high'= high,'low'=low,'close'=close)
xSubset$candleLower <- pmin(xSubset$open, xSubset$close)
  xSubset$candleMiddle <- NA
  xSubset$candleUpper <- pmax(xSubset$open, xSubset$close)
  xSubset$fill <- ''
  xSubset$fill[xSubset$open < xSubset$close] = 'white'
  xSubset$fill[xSubset$fill ==''] = 'red'
 xSubset$ma200 <- SMA(xSubset$close, 200)
  xSubset$ma50 <- SMA(xSubset$close, 50)
xSubset <-subset(xSubset, xSubset$date > start & xSubset$date < end)
 g <- ggplot(xSubset, aes(x=date, lower=candleLower, middle=candleMiddle, upper=candleUpper, ymin=low, ymax=high)) 
  g <- g + geom_boxplot(stat='identity', aes(group=date, fill=fill))
  g <- g + geom_line(aes(x=date, y=ma50))+ geom_line(aes(x=date, y=ma200))
  g 
}

candle(AAPL, start, end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the `NA` supplied for `middle`. It needs to be a continuous value. I changed it to 0s of the same length as `candleUpper` and `candleLower` and the error went away.

Does that help?

Comment: But now the second problem was occured: the value of candles in the graph is higher than 100 y.e. (on the y scale) and I want to limit this graph and to show scale beginning with the 50 or 100 (but not with 0). I tried to add in the ggplot(ylim=c(50,150)), but there was no any effect on the obrained graph.

Comment: Can you update with your new code, or even make a new question?

Comment: @RuslanSayakhov Try `g <- g + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(50, 150))`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using g + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(50, max(data))) to change the limits of your y-axis? That should work.